# deactivate_plugins function not working for me at all

Tags: wordpress

So I'm using the WordPress Plugin boilerplate and trying to remove a lite version of my plugin before going ahead with the activation of my new one. But for some reason this code simply does not execute. I have included an example below of what I am trying to do:

```
class Wp_Content_Calendar_Activator {

    /**
     * Short Description. (use period)
     *
     * Long Description.
     *
     * @since    1.0.0
     */      

    public static function activate() {
        if( is_plugin_active('hello.php') ){
             deactivate_plugins('hello.php');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** The first parameter of [`deactivate_plugins()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/deactivate_plugins/) and [`is_plugin_active()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_active/) functions refers to the basename of a plugin - see [`plugin_basename()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_basename/).

The plugin basename is the path to the plugin file relative to the plugins directory.

So, if your plugin resides in `wp-content/plugins/hello/hello.php`, the plugin basename would be `hello/hello.php`.

Example:

```
// In your hello.php file.
if ( is_plugin_active( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
    deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
}
```

or

```
// Anywhere.
if ( is_plugin_active( 'hello/hello.php' ) ) {
    deactivate_plugins( 'hello/hello.php' );
}
```

**2.** Make sure the `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` file has been loaded. It is not always included.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
deactivate_plugins( 'hello/hello.php' );
```

**3.** Terminate WordPress execution - see [`wp_die()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/).

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
deactivate_plugins( 'hello/hello.php' );
wp_die();
```